# How to remove nulls from array and a linked array whilst preserving order

Tags: javascript, arrays

I know how to remove null values from a single array using filters:

```
y = [7, 8, 9, null, null, 3, 4, null, 1]

y.filter(Number)
// [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 1]
```

However, I'd also like to remove all those of an associated array whilst preserving the order of elements in both arrays.

Say I have,

```
x = [42, 60, 70, 100, 200, 400, 500, 900, 1000]

y = [7, 8, 9, null, null, 3, 4, null, 1]
```

where an element of x is associated with y, i.e., if y[94] is *null* (which should be removed), x[94] should be removed too.

The end result should be:

```
x = [42, 60, 70, 400, 500, 1000]

y = [7, 8, 9, 3, 4, 1]
```

I've tried finding what elements are null and then manually looping through them to remove the nulls, but I'd like a more elegant solution.

Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What, specifically, are you having an issue with? Can you provide more details so we can help?

Comment: Can't you just loop over y, and then remove the elements from both arrays using the index and `.splice`?

Comment: @Cyrus No, don't splice an array while iterating over it (create a copy first). I'd rather push to new arrays.

Comment: @ChrisG Yeah, you're right!

Comment: Your original code will also eliminate any 0 from the result. Is that really intentional?

Comment: Please try: `let newX = [], newY = []; y.forEach((el, idx) => {if (el !== null) { newX.push(x[idx]); newY.push(el); }});` and share your feedback. *PS:* This should give two new arrays `newX` and `newY`. Simply assign `x = newX; y = newY;` after the `y.forEach();` and your original `x` and `y` arrays will be filtered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the arrays against each other by index as provided as the [second parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#parameters) in the callback.

```js
const x = [42, 60, 70, 100, 200, 400, 500, 900, 1000]
const y = [7, 8, 9, null, null, 3, 4, null, 1]

const xFiltered = x.filter((n, i) => n !== null && y[i] !== null);
const yFiltered = y.filter((n, i) => n !== null && x[i] !== null);

console.log(...xFiltered)
console.log(...yFiltered)
```

Answer (score 0):

The provided above answer from @pilchard will work, but

## Solution 1 (Declarative)

More declarative solution can be achieved with combination of [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/) `zip`, array filter and lodash `unzip`.

```js
import { zip, unzip } from 'lodash';

const x = [42, 60, 70, 100, 200, 400, 500, 900, 1000];
const y = [7, 8, 9, null, null, 3, 4, null, 1];

const zipped = zip(x, y).filter(([xNum, yNum]) => yNum !== null);
const [newX, newY] = unzip(zipped);
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-roentgen-eprlsx?file=/src/index.js)

⚠️ it will be a bit less performant though

### Solution 2 (More performant)

In @pilchard's case we do two array iterations, in case of solution 1 we do three iterations. But we can actually do in a single iteration with `reduce`.

```js
const x = [42, 60, 70, 100, 200, 400, 500, 900, 1000];
const y = [7, 8, 9, null, null, 3, 4, null, 1];

const [newX, newY] = x.reduce((acc, xNum, xIndex) => {
    const yNum = y[xIndex];

    if (yNum === null) return acc;

    acc[0].push(xNum);
    acc[1].push(yNum);

    return acc;
}, [[], []]);
```

Comment: Be careful with performance claims without testing. Your reduce creates a lot of arrays which is a bigger hit to performance than just two simple loops. In Chrome the two sequential filters is proving 6x faster than the reduce, spread syntax is a real killer too. (Also O(n) == O(2n))

Comment: @pilchard Yes, you're right, reduce was actually slower. Edited the answer, replaced spreads with pushes, now it is a bit faster. Thanks!